# What happens to a bounty if you accept your own answer?

Tags: support

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912666/jquery-mobile-selectmenu-need-to-select-two-times) and started a bounty.

The only answer was more general and did not help for the question.

Finally I found a solution myself and posted it. Since there was no better answer I accepted my one answer.

Now I wounder: What will happen to the bounty?

Even the extended FAQ does not answer this question: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> An accepted answer that does not meet the above criteria is still
>   ignored by the automatic-awarding system unless it is accepted during
>   the bounty period. An answer accepted during the bounty period will
>   automatically be awarded the full bounty.

But it also says I can't award a bounty to my own answer.

So what does the automatic do?

I am just asking because if it does to waste I better award it to the other answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounty is not tied to accept.

Therefore whether you accept your own answer or not, does not matter by definition.

(and the fallback you quote, ignores self-accepts since you can't award the bounty to yourself, also by definition.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added this to the FAQ.

Comment: note that accepted answer is *only* used as a fallback default at the *end* of the bounty period if the bounty owner made no other choices and accepted during the bounty period.

Comment: "you can't award the bounty to yourself" - strange, given I found the answer myself.